# use fprinft with an unknown format in matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to save the output of several evals ( don't know the input of those ) in a file. Now I don't know the tpye of those evals They could be arrays or strings or integer or anything, so I can not really write `fprinft(fileID, '%s\n', eval(somethingsomething));` since I don't know what the second parameter should be. Is there a way a for me to save those in a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the results of the eval in a local variable and check the resulting type with `class(v)` and use `printf` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just save result of eval with `fwrite()`, why would you use `fprintf`?